# Lost Connection to Ipad error while taking photos

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I am trying to add images using the camera in iPad, I am able to add max 30 images and when I am trying to add the 31st or sometimes the 32nd image, when camera opens I am getting an error like "Lost connection to iPad". I tried with allocation, memory is increasing up to 120MB while taking the pic. The images are saved to core data, but I am resizing the image to 600x600. Anybody have any idea about this issue or can you give me a clue so that I can check the reason. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, do you get the same behavior on simulator? If you don't, maybe try testing with the iPad fully charged, that will avoid any power supply bug (always happens with my iPad Air).

You said RAM is increasing up to 120MB while taking photos, how does your resize image method looks like? Test it without that method and see if memory goes down, and if it does, just don't use that method.

Also, check for memory leaks, deallocate everything you need and never keep strong references alive when you do so.

I hope that helps you somehow!